# Xcode: how to add Framework Search Paths to search paths

Tags: xcode, facebook-sdk-4.0, search-path

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZX6t.png)I'm trying to set up FacebookSDK in my react native app. when I build the project in Xcode I got an error,

> 'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h' file not found

the solution for this is to add a path to "Framework Search Paths" but I can't find then in build setting -> search paths.
there is a way the add them to settings?[image]

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Xcode Version 10.3 @AngelSyrusF

Comment: Did you tried without searching? I mean please lookout it in the particular tab of the page.

Comment: Unfortunately, they are missing there too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in the screenshot you have selected target as opaccityappClientTests. Instead please select opactiyAppClient and you can see framework search path in build settings and also please select all instead of basic near to search field

Comment: Unfortunately, they are missing there too
@Sai kiran

Comment: Please add screenshot

Comment: Please check the screenshot. im asking to send xcode screenshot but in the updated one i can see screenshot of the stackover flow.

Comment: I have edit my answer. Please check. edited part==> please select all instead of basic in build settings

Comment: Ok please select all instead of basic and check